# Better approach for using i18next library - but I don't know how to achieve it

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

My question is at the bottom of the post

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
// Bootstrap CSS
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// Bootstrap Bundle JS
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min";
import "./styles/index.scss";
import { store } from "./store/store.ts";
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import HttpApi from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { Suspense } from "react";


i18next
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    supportedLngs: ["en", "hr"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json",
    },
  });

const loadingMarkup = (
  <div className="py-4 text-center">
    <h3>Loading..</h3>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Suspense fallback={loadingMarkup}>
      {/* EVERYTHING WILL BE LOADED ONLY AFTER LANGUAGE JSON IS FETCHED 
          you can now use translations in components without fear */}
      <App />
    </Suspense>
  </Provider>
);
```

This presupposes I have json file for every language in public folder:

```
public/locales/en/translation.json:
{
  "welcome_message": "Welcome to the app"
  "go_back": "Go back"
}

public/locales/de/translation.json:
{
  "welcome_message": "Willkommen in der App"
  "go_back": "Geh zurück"
}
```

But I want to have one main json file with translations for every language, like this:

```
public/locales/translations.json:
{
  "welcome_message": {
    "en": "Welcome to the app",
    "de": "Willkommen in der App"
  }
  "go_back": {
     "en": "Go back",
     "de": "Geh zurück"
  }
}
```

When specific language is requested from browser, this main file is used to generate json file for that language. For example, if "en" is requested, returned file is:

```
{
  "welcome_message": "Welcome to the app!",
  "go_back": "Go back"
}
```

My proposed approach is more organized and less error prone. I am pretty frustrated that this is not default way how i18next works. Is it possible to achieve it somehow?

I cannot find any resource talking about this problem. AI chatbots are also pretty useless. I think it is possible to do it pretty easily by storing translation files on some separate server (like node + express) and requesting jsons from it, but I want solution with using only react.

Answer (score 0):

I would post my answer for the sake of attracting even better ideas. In the `i18next`'s [plugins documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils#i18n-formats), there are quite a few plugins for formatting the translation files.

The plugin that could help is the `i18next-shopify` one; it can allow the below formatting; though you must still specify a default language, you can do something like this:

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import ShopifyFormat from "@shopify/i18next-shopify";

i18next.use(ShopifyFormat).init({
  lng: "en",
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        welcome_message: {
          "en": "Welcome to the app",
          "de": "Willkommen in der App",
        },
        go_back: {
          "en": "Go back!",
          "de": "Geh zurück",
        },
      },
    }
  }
});

i18next.t("welcome_message.en"); // -> Welcome to the app
i18next.t("go_back.de"); // -> Geh zurück
```

---

However, I would say even though this solution could work, it is a solution with an extra step, and `react-i18next` (and also `i18next`) does always prefer the format of `./locales/{language}/{namespace}.json`.

It is just a common practice to separate translation files with languages, and if you want to clarify the structure of the files, you can use `namespace` as the [principles](https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces) suggest.

Hope the above answer will help.